# What does it mean for the shape of an image tensor to be (64, 64)? Does that mean there are no channels?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, tensor

I was exploring the images of the dataset : [Tiny Imagenet](https://www.kaggle.com/akash2sharma/tiny-imagenet) and I found that most of the image tensors have shapes (64, 64, 3) i.e. images of height and width 64 and 64 respectively and three channels for Red, Green and Blue. But some of the image tensors in the dataset have shape (64, 64).


Does it mean that there are no channels? How is it possible?

EDIT - I downloaded this image with tensor shape (64, 64):

[image]

EDIT - Is it possible that it has one channel of some other colour space like Lab? (here b refers to the colours from blue to yellow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is equivalent to (64, 64, 1) but most libraries collapse the last axis. It means you have only one channel, probably a grayscale image. Is it possible that your dataset is mixed between RGB and grayscale images?

Comment: The image doesn't appear to be grayscale, is it possible that is has one dimension in some other colour space such as Lab? with just the 'b' part (as it seems to go from Blue to Yellow) ?

Comment: Have you used matplotlib to draw it? You can pass `cmap='gray'` in imshow to display it as grayscale.

Comment: Yes, I've used matplotlib. Actually I just drew it for visualisation and analysing the images for I needed to train a machine learning model with it. So, there's no use displaying the image in grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

You have a channel dimension - only it's of `shape`=1 - you have a single color channel which means this is a gray-scale image.

If you are using `PIL.Image` to read the images, you can force it to have three channels by

```
Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
```

You will have `shape` of (64, 64, 3), but note that all the channels will be identical.